# Use 3rd monitor only for Windows VM

Tags: virtualbox, windows, virtualization, vmware

I cannot use my 3rd monitor on Ubuntu. My USB to VGA cable has no drivers for linux. Therefore I want to ask if there's a way to use my 3rd monitor with my USB to VGA cable through a VM where Windows is installed.

You would "save my life" if you could help me. :)

Kind regards

Comment: An HDMI to VGA adapter shouldn't  require special drivers because it presents itself to the system like any other HDMI monitor. Are you sure your system supports 3 monitors?

Comment: It does need a driver because the adapter is from fresco logic and they only support windows. Ubuntu should support a 3rd monitor. My hardware also does because I had no problems when I used Windows. Do you think I could use the 3rd monitor if I run a Windows VM?

Comment: Fresco logic is best known for their USB video solutions. Are you maybe talking about a _USB_ to VGA adapter?

Comment: Whooops, I dont know why I keep writing HDMI but yes, USB to VGA is what I mean.

Comment: I suggest you try it yourself and tell us if it worked. Install virtualbox and the virtualbox extension pack, which is needed for USB pass through . Setup a windows VM, pass the USB device through to the guest and see what you get. Maybe try installing the drivers in the VM. If it doesn't work, you may want to look for an adapter with DisplayLink hardware because they provide Ubuntu drivers.

Comment: As a side note, what you want to achieve is apparently possible with DisplayLink hardware and windows 10 in a virtualbox VM as stated [here](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/544870-unable-to-install-displaylink-software-on-a-window).